# Is there a standard Java 8 FunctionalInterface for a block throwing a checked exception?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

Callable throws Exception, Runnable doesn't.

Is there anything standard that looks like

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface TypedBlock<E extends Exception> {
    public void run() throws E;
}
```

Comment: There isn't AFAIK. `Callable<Void>` and `return null;`.

Comment: Note that implementers are free to define more restricted exception types themselves: `class MyCallable implements Callable<Void> { public Void call() throws IOException {...} }` == "I will only throw IOExceptions"

Comment: That return null is a pain in the butt with lambdas and method references.

Comment: Bah, you're obviously using this for custom code. Use your own interface.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no built in functionality as I know. But you can use an external library for that (and many other cool features).

You can either use [JOOL](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOL), where you can use the [Unchecked](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOL/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jooq/lambda/Unchecked.java) class for this.

The example from there page demonstrates this with an `IOException`

```
Arrays.stream(dir.listFiles()).forEach(
    Unchecked.consumer(file -> { System.out.println(file.getCanonicalPath()); })
);
```

Another (and in my opinion better) approach would be to use a functional designed library like [Functionaljava](https://github.com/functionaljava/functionaljava).

A good approach would be to wrap your task in a `Validation` to decide afterwards, if the result was successful. This could look like this:

```
TypedBlock<IOException> foo = ...;

// do your work
final Validation<IOException, Unit> validation = Try.f(() -> {
  foo.run();
  return Unit.unit(); // Unit equals nothing in functional languages
})._1();

// check if we got a failure
if (validation.isFail()) {
  System.err.println("Got err " + validation.fail());
}

// check for success
if (validation.isSuccess()) {
  System.out.println("All was good :-)");
}

// this will just print out a message if we got no error
validation.forEach(unit -> System.out.println("All was good"));
```

Answer (score 2):

There is `java.lang.AutoCloseable` which has a `()->{} throws Exception` signature, however, it is burden with a predefined semantic. So for an ad-hoc use it might be suitable but when you design an API, I recommend defining your own `interface`.

Note that your specialized interface could still extend `Callable<Void>` to be a standard `interface`:

```
interface Block<E extends Exception> extends Callable<Void>{
    void run() throws E;
    @Override default Void call() throws E { run(); return null; }
    /** This little helper method avoids type casts when a Callable is expected */
    static <T extends Exception> Block<T> make(Block<T> b) { return b; }
}
```

This way you can use your `Block` interface with existing APIs:

```
// Example
ExecutorService e=Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
try {
    e.submit(Block.make(()->{ throw new IOException("test"); })).get();
} catch (InterruptedException ex) {
    throw new AssertionError(ex);
} catch (ExecutionException ex) {
    System.out.println("received \""+ex.getCause().getMessage()+'"');
}
e.shutdown();
```

Note the trick with the static method `Block.make`. Without it you would have to cast the lambda expression to `(Block<IOException>)` instead of profiting from the improved type inference. This is only necessary where a `Callable` is expected, for your own API where a `Block` is expected, you can use lambda expressions and method references directly.